# component is not getting updated to the UI after gettring the value from Spotify API

Tags: reactjs

here I am getting the values of playlist to the console, but not able to show it to the UI.

```
function Sidebar() {
    const [{ playlists }, dispatch] = useStateProviderValue();

    console.log(playlists);
    playlists?.items?.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.name);
    });
    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <img
                className="sidebar__logo"
                src="https://getheavy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/spotify2019-830x350.jpg"
                alt=""
            />
            <SidebarOption Icon={HomeIcon} title="Home" />
            <SidebarOption Icon={SearchIcon} title="Search" />
            <SidebarOption Icon={LibraryMusicIcon} title="Your Library" />

            <br />
            <strong className="sidebar__title">PLAYLISTS</strong>
            <hr />
    

            {playlists?.items?.forEach(playlist => {
                <SidebarOption title={playlist.name} />
            })}


        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: ForEach will only loop through an array, while the map will return you a new array with a modified value.

Answer (score 2):

ForEach will only loop through an array, while the map will return you a new array with a modified value.

The render method always needs a returned JSX to render which you won't get in the case of forEach.

```js
render () {
     //correct way
     return items.map((item,index) => 
     <SidebarOption title={item.name} key={index} />) 
     // returns modified/maped items JSX
    }
    
render () {
     return items.forEach((item,index) => 
     <SidebarOption title={item.name} key={index} />) 
     // returns undefined
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `map` instead `forEach` because `map` returns an array.

```
{playlists?.items?.map((playlist, index) => {
   <SidebarOption title={playlist.name} key={index} />
})}
```

Comment: {playlists?.items?.map((playlist, index) => (
   <SidebarOption title={playlist.name} key={index} />
))}